# login view not logging user in

Tags: python, django, view

I'm building my first django app. I'm trying to create a slightly customized authentication system but my login view doesn't work.

When I create a user, my register view creates the user, authenticates it and then redirects to another url properly.

If then I log out and got to my login form and post to the login view, I keep being redirected to the same form. my views.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from general import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout, authenticate



# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'general/home.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')


def loginView(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
            if user is not None:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                     "Welcome back, {}".format(user))
                login(request, user)
                return home(request)

    return render(request, 'general/loginForm.html', {'form': form})

def logoutView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = forms.MyCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request,messages.SUCCESS,
                                 "Welcome to ShopGlue, in 3 steps you'll be up and running!")
            user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return profile(request)
        else:
            return render(request, 'general/registerForm.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = forms.MyCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'general/registerForm.html', {'form': form})

@login_required()
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'general/profile.html')
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from general import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^login$', views.loginView, name="loginView"),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logoutView, name="logoutView"),
    url(r'^register$', views.register, name="register"),
    url(r'^profile$', views.profile, name="profile"),
]
```

I can't for the life of me, figure out what I am doing wrong. Some feedback would be very much appreciated.

Thank you guys.

Edit: This is MyCreationForm():

```
class MyCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
        ]
```

It's just extending UserCreation form provided by django.
Also, in the admin when I click on one user and try to see its password, I see this:

algorithm: pbkdf2_sha256 iterations: 20000 salt: cU32aI****** hash: sABS3A**************************************

Which means that the password has been hashed before it was stored.

Any ideas on how can I fix my login view? :(

Comment: You haven't shown the code for MyCreationForm, but I would guess it is just saving the user with the password as cleartext, which isn't valid when you come to log in.

Comment: First, I recommend you to read PEP8 how to write nice / stylish Python codes. Second, You can shorten the logout view. Just add above @login_required and in the function simple login(request) and the return ...

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i see with your view is your return statement after login() call. Why return a view and not an HttpResponse object

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Fixed! But the original problem persists. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out.

```
form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
```

Should be:

```
form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
```